# git remote -v explanation

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I'm using `git remote -v` to see my remote repository.

```
myname@DESKTOP-0SD47KB MINGW64 ~/Desktop/maevenNetbeans/MyProject(master)
    $ git remote -v
    origin  https://github.com/Myname/MyProject.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/Myname/MyProject.git (push)
    origin2 https://github.com/Myname/MyProject(fetch)
    origin2 https://github.com/Myname/MyProject(push)
```

When i created the repository, i linked only one remote repository.

My question is why i'm getting two linked remote repisotory?

What is the meaning of the fetch and push keywords in this context. I know that pushing is for sending and fetching is for retrieving.

is the origin2 a local repository?

Comment: I think you mistakenly added origin2. You can do 'git remote remove origin2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

origin2 is simply the result of (possibly by mistake) a [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem):

```
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/...
```

Since the URL is the same as `origin`, a git fetch will *not* fetch twice.

As commented, a simple [`git remote remove origin2`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emremoveem) would rectify the issue.